# Imagemagick batch converting memory overload

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, imagemagick

I must to convert about billion of images from jp2 to jpg...

I create such .bat

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  for %%f in ("%%~d\*.jp2") do (
    convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~ff" -quality 25 "%%~dpf\jpg\%%~nf.jpg"
  )
)
```

but when it convert's over ~ 100 000 windows throw's me error's with free memory etc...  How can i do that memory is used more humanity? So that imageconverter? if yes then release that memory....  Maybe there are ways to thread this ot something else?

Now i get in concolse free memory error's and also window's throw erro's too...

Also if i delete limit memory 0 -limit map 0  i have the same problem...

Comment: What's up @brabertaser19 .... Curious if you had a chance yet to look over the answer I provided and give me some feedback regarding the matter so I can help you get a 100% working solution to this problem since that's what I do for a living. You got me for free to help if what I've already provided has not already helped if you've gotten a chance to look it over yet. Otherwise consider that as such and also checking that grey check mark to the upper right of the answer provided and turning that thing green.

Answer (score 0):

Below works well for me so in case you find it helpful in resolving the issue with the memory for these commands in your particular case, I'm providing you an answer.

I know your example is using a **FOR /D** loop and using that to iterate into another **FOR** loop but using a single [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop along with the [**DIR**](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command and applicable switches seems to help ensure each iterated conversion, etc. is in a new instance of memory.

---

### Overwrite Converted Files In-place

```
@ECHO ON

SET Source=C:\SourceFolder\Images
SET Ext=*.jp2

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR /A-D /S /B "%Source%\%Ext%"') DO convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~A" -quality 25 "%%~A"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Output Converted Files to an Output Directory

```
@ECHO ON

SET Source=C:\SourceFolder\Images
SET Output=C:\Output\jpg
SET Ext=*.jp2

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR /A-D /S /B "%Source%\%Ext%"') DO convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~A" -quality 25 "%Output%\%%~NXA"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**DIR**](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)